# $\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}^5+\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)-50)=50\;\;$ and $\;\;\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}x)=100$ then $\;x=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> What is the value of $x$ ?$$\begin{cases}
>  {\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}^5+\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)-50)=50}
>  \\ {\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}x)=100\;\;,\;\;\alpha>1\;\;,\;\; x>1} 
>  \end{cases}$$

Here is my work:

First off, I think $\log^5_{\alpha}$ is a typo in the original problem and it is the same as $\log_{\alpha}5$. We have

$$\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}x)=2\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5+\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)-50)$$

$$\log_{\alpha}x=(\log_{\alpha}5+\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)-50)^2$$

And from $\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}x)=100$ we have $\log_{\alpha}x=\alpha^{100}$.  Hence
$$\log_{\alpha}5+\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)-50=\alpha^{50}$$
$$\log_{\alpha}(5\log_{\alpha}5)=\alpha^{50}+50$$But I'm not sure how to find $x=\alpha^{\alpha^{100}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\log_{x}(\log_{x}5+\log_{x}(\log_{x}5)-50)-50$ is a strictly decreasing function, so there is only one solution for $x$.
By trial and error we find that $f(x)=0$ when $\log_{x}(\log_{x}5)=50$.
Therefore  $\log_{\alpha}(\log_{\alpha}5)=50$
$$\implies {\alpha^{50}}=\log_{\alpha}5$$
$$\implies \alpha^{\alpha^{50}}=5$$

---

Value of $ \alpha^{\alpha^{50}}$ increases with increase in $\alpha$ so there can be only one solution for $\alpha^{\alpha^{50}}=5$.
We can see that $\alpha=5^{1/25}$ satisfies the condition.
Therefore $$x=\alpha^{\alpha^{100}}=5^{25}$$

Comment: Thanks! And $x=5^{\log_{\alpha}5}$ ?